# Compare 2 different arrays with same indexer but different amount of values in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

looking for your help.

I do have 2 arrays

```
a = [["01000340001001", 0, 1122, "Triju vai vair─üku dz─½vok─╝u m─üjas", "Dz─½vojam─ü ─ōka", 27, "Aleksandra ─īaka iela 110, R─½ga"], ["01000340002001", 0, 1122, "Triju vai vair─üku dz─½vok─╝u m─üjas", "Dz─½vojam─ü ─ōka", 15, "Aleksandra ─īaka iela 108, R─½ga"], ["01000340002002", 0, 1122, "Triju vai vair─üku dz─½vok─╝u m─üjas", "Dz─½vojam─ü ─ōka", 4, "Aleksandra ─īaka iela 108, R─½ga"], ["01000340002005", 0, 1252, "Noliktavas, rezervu─üri, bunkuri un silosi", "Noliktava", 1, "Aleksandra ─īaka iela 108B, R─½ga"], ["01000340002006", 0, 1252, "Noliktavas, rezervu─üri, bunkuri un silosi", "Noliktava", 1, "Aleksandra ─īaka iela 108, R─½ga"], ["01000340002006", 0, 1252, "Noliktavas, rezervu─üri, bunkuri un silosi", "Noliktava", 1, "Aleksandra ─īaka iela 108B, R─½ga"], ["01000340002008", 0, 1274, "Citas, iepriek┼Ī neklasific─ōtas, ─ōkas", "Nojume", 0, nil]]
```

Another one

```
b = [["01000340002001", 0, 1122, "Triju vai vair─üku dz─½vok─╝u m─üjas", "Dz─½vojam─ü ─ōka", 15], ["01000340002002", 0, 1122, "Triju vai vair─üku dz─½vok─╝u m─üjas", "Dz─½vojam─ü ─ōka", 4], ["01000340002006", 0, 1252, "Noliktavas, rezervu─üri, bunkuri un silosi", "Noliktava", 1]]
```

I need to remove from `a` those arrays, that are in `b` by indexers as i think(e.g. remove duplicated).

What i was trying is to do this

```
all = []
all = a.collect {|key, value | key} - b.collect {|key, value | key}
# ["01000340002005", "01000340001001", "01000340002008"]
```

And then select arrays that i need

```
a.select { |key, value| key == b }
# ["01000340002008", 0, 1274, "Citas, iepriek┼Ī neklasific─ōtas, ─ōkas", "Nojume", 0, nil]
```

As outcome i get only 1 array, but should 3.

Could someone please suggest me how to make it work? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
b_indexes = b.map(&:first)
a.delete_if { |arr| b_indexes.include?(arr.first) }
#~> [
      ["01000340001001", 0, 1122, "Triju vai vair─üku dz─½vok─╝u m─üjas", "Dz─½vojam─ü ─ōka", 27, "Aleksandra ─īaka iela 110, R─½ga"],
      ["01000340002005", 0, 1252, "Noliktavas, rezervu─üri, bunkuri un silosi", "Noliktava", 1, "Aleksandra ─īaka iela 108B, R─½ga"],
      ["01000340002008", 0, 1274, "Citas, iepriek┼Ī neklasific─ōtas, ─ōkas", "Nojume", 0, nil]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that elements of `a` differs from elements of `b` for having a string more as last element.

So, you could just [Array#reject!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) comparing the whole element of `b`:

```
a.reject! { |e| b.include? e[0...-1] }
```

But if only the first element of each nested array is the signal, mapping `b` against the first element before and then rejecting elements based on that map is the correct way.

Note that Array#reject! affects the original array.

Answer (score 0):

[assoc](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Array.html#method-i-assoc) is nice for this:

```
p b.map{|ar| a.assoc(ar.first)}
```